# XML::Twig - identifying blobs that do not contain an element

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, azure-storage, xml-twig

I am using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) to parse output of Azure's `list-blob` REST API.

In particular, I am looking to identify and delete uncommitted orphan blobs, and I am unsure as to how best go about using `XML::Twig` efficiently to do this. I don't even know where to start.

Ultimately I need to retrieve the `<Name>` element of the orphaned blobs.

The [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) states:

> **Uncommitted Blobs in the Response**
>
> Uncommitted blobs are listed in the response only if the
>   *include=uncommittedblobs* parameter was specified on the URI.
>   Uncommitted blobs listed in the response do not include any of the
>   following elements:
>
> ```
> Last-Modified
> Etag
> Content-Type
> Content-Encoding
> Content-Language
> Content-MD5
> Cache-Control
> Metadata
> ```

Therefore, in the following simplified example, you can see an orphan blob called "test"  because the `<Blob></Blob>` block does not contain any of the above elements.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="https://my**account.blob.core.windows.net/"
  ContainerName="testonly">
  <Blobs>
    <Blob>
      <Name>test</Name>
      <Properties>
        <Content-Length>0</Content-Length>
        <BlobType>BlockBlob</BlobType>
        <LeaseStatus>unlocked</LeaseStatus>
        <LeaseState>available</LeaseState>
      </Properties>
    </Blob>
  </Blobs>
  <NextMarker/>
</EnumerationResults>
```

UPDATE :

Actually, I might have oversimplified.  The accepted answer does not appear to work with the below, it prints everything :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="https://my**account.blob.core.windows.net/" ContainerName="testonly">
<Blobs>
    <Blob>
        <Name>data/users/docx</Name>
        <Properties>
            <Last-Modified>Wed, 10 May 2017 20:21:25 GMT</Last-Modified>
            <Etag>0x8D497E221E7A5AF</Etag>
            <Content-Length>125632</Content-Length>
            <Content-Type>application/octet-stream</Content-Type>
            <Content-Encoding/>
            <Content-Language/>
            <Content-MD5/>
            <Cache-Control/>
            <Content-Disposition/>
            <BlobType>BlockBlob</BlobType>
            <LeaseStatus>unlocked</LeaseStatus>
            <LeaseState>available</LeaseState>
        </Properties>
    </Blob>
    <Blob>
        <Name>test</Name>
        <Properties>
            <Content-Length>0</Content-Length>
            <BlobType>BlockBlob</BlobType>
            <LeaseStatus>unlocked</LeaseStatus>
            <LeaseState>available</LeaseState>
        </Properties>
    </Blob>
</Blobs>
<NextMarker/>
</EnumerationResults>
```

My code :

```
sub blob_parse {
        my $blob = $_;
        $blob->first_child($_) and return
        for qw( Last-Modified Etag Content-Type Content-Encoding
                Content-Language Content-MD5 Cache-Control Metadata);
        say "orph: ".$blob->first_child('Name')->text;
}

sub parseAndDelete {
        ### ORPHAN
        $twig_handlers = {'Blobs/Blob' => \&blob_parse};
        $twig = new XML::Twig(twig_handlers=>$twig_handlers);
        $twig->parse($message);
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that the XML will be mal-formed, with a closing `</Blob>` tag but no opening `<Blob>`? I doubt if `XML::Twig` will handle that.

Comment: @Borodin  No !  That was just a copy paste fail on my part (copy/paste from Linux via TMUX sometimes does weird stuff.  I have fixed it.

Comment: I spotted that. I have updated my answer and put a fix in a comment on **choroba's**. You can pick whichever you like!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a handler for `Blob`, do nothing if any of the elements is present, otherwise print the name. Use the `first_child` method to inspect the internal structure of a blob.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use XML::Twig;

my $xml = '...';

my $twig = 'XML::Twig'->new(twig_handlers => {
    Blob => sub {
        my $properties = $_->first_child('Properties');
        $properties->first_child($_) and return
            for qw( Last-Modified Etag Content-Type Content-Encoding
                    Content-Language Content-MD5 Cache-Control Metadata
                  );
        say $_->first_child('Name')->text;
    },
});
$twig->parse($xml);
```

Comment: I think this needs to be `my $properties = $blob->first_child('Properties')` and `$properties->first_child($_) and return ... `.

Comment: @Borodin I'm retesting with this... per my comment to you below, it actually doesn't work on "real" data  ... serves me right for over-simplifying my sample !  I have updated my question with added data.

Comment: Updated according to the new sample.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

There's no reason to use the system of callbacks that `XML::Twig` provides unless your XML data is enormous and the corresponding data structure consumes too much memory, which is unlikely for data obtained in an internet message

I would implement it this way

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use XML::Twig;
use List::Util 'none';

my @unwanted = qw/
    Last-Modified Etag Content-Type Content-Encoding
    Content-Language Content-MD5 Cache-Control Metadata
/;

my $twig = 'XML::Twig'->new;

$twig->parsefile('blob.xml');

for my $blob ( $twig->find_nodes('Blobs/Blob') ) {

    if ( none { $blob->find_nodes("Properties/$_") } @unwanted ) {
        say $_->text for $blob->find_nodes('Name');
    }
}
```

#### output

```
test
```

---

If your XML is in fact well-formed and your example data is a mistake, then it is simple to print the text content of all `Name` elements

I have used this data

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="https://my**account.blob.core.windows.net/"
  ContainerName="testonly">
  <Blobs>
    <Blob>
      <Name>test</Name>
      <Properties>
        <Content-Length>0</Content-Length>
        <BlobType>BlockBlob</BlobType>
        <LeaseStatus>unlocked</LeaseStatus>
        <LeaseState>available</LeaseState>
      </Properties>
    </Blob>
  </Blobs>
  <NextMarker/>
</EnumerationResults>
```

#### Perl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use XML::Twig;

my $t = XML::Twig->new;
$t->parsefile( 'blob.xml');

say $_->text for $t->find_nodes('Blobs/Blob/Name');
```

#### output

```
test
```

Comment: " it is simple to print the text content of all Name elements" .... yeah, I figured that one out already .... the point of my question was I wanted a subset of elements. `list-blob` returns everything, I just wanted the orphans as per the doc excerpt I posted.  I think @choroba has the answer.

Comment: @LittleCode: I'm sorry, I was trying to understand the relationship between *uncommited* and *orphan* blobs (you show the doumentation for *uncommited* blobs, and never use the term again) and whether that somehow meant a `<Blob>` element with the opening tag missing. Your example data shows exactly one `<Blob>` and you want its name, and my code works fine with that. It would have been better to explain your terminology and to offer some data that required the filtering that is the point of your question. Fortunately **choroba** understood your intent.

Comment: no problem, I was trying to keep my example simple, but I guess I oversimplified !

Comment: @LittleCode: I've updated my answer. You may prefer a solution that avoids using callbacks and simply builds a static data structure that you can navigate. I have also fixed a bug in **choroba's** example whereby he looks in the wrong place for the elements that mustn't appear in the message.

Comment: You may well have had a valid point about over-simplified sample XML.  I tried choroba's answer with "real" code and it prints every name, not just the excluded ones.   I have updated my question accordingly and temporarily removed answer status from choroba.

Comment: @LittleCode: I've tested my update against your new data and it's working fine.

Comment: Yeah great. Thanks for that.  Its a shame you can't accept two answers here. So I've given you a bunch of upvotes and left the answer with Choroba as the overall concept was still good, just a little bug.   But  your answer was equally interesting, as you say, sometimes callbacks are overkill.  Thanks again !